# How do I create a Python ctypes pointer to an array of pointers

Tags: python, pointers, ctypes

I need to learn how to handle the `char**` in the C++ method below through Python ctypes.
I was doing fine calling other methods that only need single pointers by using `create_string_buffer()`, but this method requires a pointer to an array of pointers.

```
ladybugConvertToMultipleBGRU32(
         LadybugContext          context,
        const  LadybugImage * pImage,
        unsigned char**        arpDestBuffers,
         LadybugImageInfo *   pImageInfo  )
```

How do I create a pointer to an array of six `create_string_buffer(7963648)` buffers in ctypes to pass to this C++ method for writing?

```
arpDestBuffers = pointer to [create_string_buffer(7963648) for i in xrange(6)]
```

Thank you for any help.

---

Both the answers given below work. I just didn't realize I had another problem in my code which prevented me from seeing the results right away.
The first example is just as Luc wrote:

```
SixBuffers = c_char_p * 6
arpDestBuffers = SixBuffers(
            *[c_char_p(create_string_buffer(7963648).raw) for i in xrange(6)] )
```

The second example coming from omu_negru's answer is:

```
arpDestBuffers = (POINTER(c_char) * 6)()
arpDestBuffers[:] = [create_string_buffer(7963648) for i in xrange(6)]
```

Both are accepted by the function and overwritten. Typing `print repr(arpDestBuffers[4][:10])` before and after calling the function gives:

```
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
'\x15\x10\x0e\xff\x15\x10\x0e\xff\x14\x0f'
```

which shows that the function successfully overwrote the buffer with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after you create all the string_buffers you need by calling create_string_buffer you can create an array for them with :

```
var=(POINTER(c_char)*size)()  /* pointer_to_pointer */
```

Then you can fill it up by indexing it with `var[index]` and finally just call your function using it as an argument.... Works fine for me and i just tested it on a function with the signature `void test_fn(char*,char**,unsigned char);` written in C

Comment: I guess I don't know enough about Python to implement what you suggested. Where does 'your_pointer_to_pointer' come from? Thanks

Comment: sorry about that...was supposed to be a comment but i guess it just slipped....now it should be ok :) you make a new type (pointer array of size "size") and call the constructor and bind it to var.

Comment: To fill the var I have:`var[:] = [create_string_buffer(7963648) for i in xrange(6)]`. It seems that this var is what I want but I'm still getting a `ctypes.ArgumentError` when I try to pass it to the method.   `ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 2`

Comment: The var did work! Thanks. I just found that `parameter 2` actually means the 2nd parameter. I assumed it meant the 3rd. So now both parameters are good now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Something like

```
SixBuffers = c_char_p * 6
arpDestBuffers = SixBuffers(*[c_char_p(create_string_buffer(7963648).raw) for i in xrange(6)])
```

Didin't try myself, so not sure that it works. Inspired by http://python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/tutorial.html#arrays

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but it's not working for me.
`SixBuffers = c_char_p * 6
arpDestBuffers = SixBuffers(*[c_char_p(create_string_buffer('\x00'*10).raw) for i in xrange(6)])
print type(arpDestBuffers), repr(arpDestBuffers)
print type(arpDestBuffers[0]), repr(arpDestBuffers[0])` This has the following output: `<class '__main__.c_char_p_Array_6'> <__main__.c_char_p_Array_6 object at 0x01CB9F80>
<type 'str'> ''`

Comment: What happens when your call your C API? The buffers is empty? Is it the problem?

Comment: When passing the arpDestBuffers to the method, I get this error:`ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 2` It's the same for most of the things I've tried.